# Abbreviations in natural language processing

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I work on sentiment analysis . Abbreviations are one of the most widely used in natural languages. I used Spellcheker to correct spelling mistakes, and one of the problems with using this method is that it translates Abbreviations into the closest word to English. This affects the sentiment detection. Is there any code or a method that these Abbreviations can be extended according to their neighbor words?

Answer (score 1):

hello here is an example that might be useful

```
    import spacy
    from scispacy.abbreviation import AbbreviationDetector
    nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    abbreviation_pipe=AbbreviationDetector(nlp)
    text="stackoverflow (SO) is a question and answer site for professional and enth_usiast programmers.SO roxks!"
    nlp.add_pipe(abbreviation_pipe)
    def replace_acronyms(text):
       doc=nlp(txt)
       altered_tok=[tok.text for tok in doc]
       print(doc._.abbreviations)
       for abrv in doc._.abbreviations:
          altered_tok[abrv.start]=str(abrv._.long_form)
    return(" "join(altered_tok))
  replace_acronyms(text)
  replace_acronyms("Top executives of Microsoft(MS) and General Motors (GM) met today in NewYord")
```

Comment: https://github.com/allenai/SciSpaCy#abbreviationdetector   This might be specific to abbreviations in the biomedical domain?